# Cannot install sound and display driver without Windows xp service pack 3

Tags: windows-xp, audio, compact-disc, display-driver

I have already installed Windows XP Service Pack 3  and downloaded the sound and display driver from the manufacturer website but when I try and install it, I get an error message that it was not successfully installed and it demand Windows XP Service Pack 3 CD.

I don't have the Windows XP service pack 3 CD.

Is there any other way to sort this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: You will need to upgrade to Sevice Pack 3 if you want assistance.  Service Pack 2 is not supported by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect the installation of SP3 was not successful. You can find out what version you have, click start, right click on My Computer and select properties to see.

I suggest you remove it from your machine (via Add Remove programs) and then you can download it via the normal Windows Updates and re-install. [More details](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322389).

Comment: my operrating system version is microsoft windows xo professional version 2002 servie pack 3 which i have downloaed and to install sound driver system the file `kuser.dll`on windows xp professional service pack 3 cd is needed. such error is coming.since I have downloaded service pack 3 i dont have cd. thn in this case how to install sound driver

Answer (score 0):

You could always install SP3 without the CD. That should solve your problem. Look at this guide here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/help/learn-how-to-install-windows-xp-service-pack-3-sp3